# Python SymPy 1.3 simplify symbolic matrix calculation

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following code for a symbolic matrix calculation

```
from sympy import *
A = MatrixSymbol( 'A', 3, 3 )
B = MatrixSymbol( 'B', 3, 3 )
C = MatrixSymbol( 'C', 3, 3 )
Z = A * ( A + B ) * C.inverse() * ( A + B ).transpose()
Z.expand()
```

This gives me the following result

```
A( A + B ) C^-1 ( A^T + B^T )
```

But I want the expanded result

```
A * A * C^-1 * A^T + A * B C^-1 * A^T + A * A C^-1 * B^T + A * B C^-1 * B^T
```

Could I ask you guys that how to do it ? Thank you very much

Comment: any one could help ?

Comment: I guess there is no way to do it by sympy. It has no such function in MatrixSymbol class.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to expand matrix operations in sympy. The expression from the result you have above is the only way to view the result. [Expansion functions available in sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html) include `expand()`, `expand_trig()`, `expand_power_exp()`, `expand_power_base()`, `expand_log()`, `expand_func()` and `hyperexpand()`, none of which seem to work with your matrix expression.

The `simplify` function doesn't seem to work either if we wanted to evaluate your desired output to compare to the sympy output of `Z`

```
simplify(A*A*C.inverse()*A.transpose() + A*A*C.inverse()*B.transpose() + A*B*C.inverse()*A.transpose() + A*B*C.inverse()*B.transpose())
>>> A*A*C^-1*A.T + A*A*C^-1*B.T + A*B*C^-1*A.T + A*B*C^-1*B.T
```

which clearly isn't in the same form as the sympy expression for `Z`.

Even if you were to just test your desired output against the output of sympy, you still get a False result

```
Z == A * A * C.inverse() * A.transpose() + A * B*C.inverse() * A.transpose() + A * A*C.inverse() * B.transpose() + A * B*C.inverse() * B.transpose()
>>> False
```

We cannot define matrices `A`, `B` and `C` with known values for each index and then evaluate the expressions you have above to compare their outputs because `MutableDenseMatrix` objects do not have an `inverse` attribute.

If you want to actually compare the two expressions to see if they are equal, you could use numpy and compare both expressions with known matrix values. This is quite convoluted and wont work for very complex expressions, but it does work for simple expressions.

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
# define 3 numpy arrays
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B = np.array([[0,0.1,-4],[19,0.67,6],[-1,99,5]])
C = np.array([[1,2,-1],[4,5,6],[-2,2,0]])

# sympy expression, compute iteratively
Z1 = np.dot(A, A + B)
Z1 = np.dot(Z1, np.linalg.inv(C))
Z1 = np.dot(Z1, A.T + B.T)
print(Z1)
>>>[[ 143.22088889 -672.5076     -100.24      ]
   [-239.47685185 4558.45416667 3597.5       ]
   [  65.1457037   -94.81393333  519.56      ]]

# desired expression
p1 = np.dot(A, A)
p1 = np.dot(p1, np.linalg.inv(C))
p1 = np.dot(p1, A.T)

p2 = np.dot(A, B)
p2 = np.dot(p2, np.linalg.inv(C))
p2 = np.dot(p2, A.T)

p3 = np.dot(A, A)
p3 = np.dot(p3, np.linalg.inv(C))
p3 = np.dot(p3, B.T)

p4 = np.dot(A, B)
p4 = np.dot(p4, np.linalg.inv(C))
p4 = np.dot(p4, B.T)

Z2 = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4
print(Z2)
>>>[[ 143.22088889 -672.5076     -100.24      ]
   [-239.47685185 4558.45416667 3597.5       ]
   [  65.1457037   -94.81393333  519.56      ]]

np.isclose(Z1,Z2)
>>>[[ True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True]
```

So we can see that the sympy expression `Z1` and your desired expression `Z2` are in fact the same, given the matrices above.